# I'm attempting to make a discord bot but I'm having trouble running it

Tags: node.js

Hi so I'm pretty new to code and I'm trying my best with just creating a simple discord bot, but I can't even run it or turn it on to begin with. When I use "node ." or "node index.js" it gives me this.

```
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js)'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Madison\Desktop\BeepBoop\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)      
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Madison\Desktop\BeepBoop\index.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)        
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\Madison\\Desktop\\BeepBoop\\index.js' ]
```

Someone mentioned installing discord.js but that still isn't working either. Its very simple so far here is the bot

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js)');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'NzQ1NzY2OTQ2NDQzNjI0NDg4.Xz2jlw.sKIp-VYeOdTHTrBWmu2DOnHlgq4';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})
```

bot.login(token);

and here are the .json package contents

```
{
  "name": "beep-boop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Upsetti",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

pls help :'>

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. You are currently saying:

```
require('discord.js)')
```

It should be:

```
require('discord.js') // Note the ")" inside the quotes has been removed
```

I am not too familiar with discord, but you may have shared a private token in your question. If this is the case you may want to obtain a new token, and keep this new one private.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much I am so very dumb I just spent like an hour trying to figure out what was wrong and it was such a tiny dumb mistake. And the bots just for testing purposes but I'll still be sure to generate a new token. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer but please do not add your token online, otherwise generate a new one because there are people on the website looking for Discord tokens to hack and destroy your bot.